# How can you read for a specific value from a binary file starting from the end of the file?

Tags: c#, pdf, filestream, reverse, binaryreader

I am trying to figure out how to actually (appropriately) read for the PDF trailer *Byte_offset_of_last_cross-reference_section* from a PDF file.

According to the [PDF 1.7 (ISO 32000-1:2008)](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) specification, the file structure is designed in a way that it should be read from the end of the file. Here is an example of what a simplified (minimal) trailer looks like when I use a `StreamReader` and read the file line-by-line (UTF8 Encoding):

> **trailer**
>   << key1 value1
>        key2 value2
>        …
>        keyn valuen
>   >>
>   **startxref**
>   *Byte_offset_of_last_cross-reference_section*
>   %%EOF

```
trailer
<</Root 7 0 R /Size 7>>
startxref
696
%%EOF
```

The value I want to somehow grab is the *696* value. I'm just not sure how to do that using a BinaryReader starting from the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Seek` method, see [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/seek) for examples. You can use SeekOrigin.End as argument, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/883dhyx0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for other options

example:

```
using (var reader = File.Open(...))
{
    reader.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.End);
    //...
}
```

You can start reading backwards in a loop till you get to the `startxref` marker (or anything that helps you know that you can read `696`) or assume a length of 100 bytes from the end of the file and then do a lookup in that small array as Anthony suggested in the comment below.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please reflect the core of what you are trying to show in your answer by providing a code snippet or a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: It might be better to start from `reader.Length - 50` and continue to seek forward until you find what you need. Not sure how good it would be to actually seek 1 byte at a time backwards in a file.

Comment: Actually if you want to emulate the laxity of e.g. Adobe Reader, you would start from `reader.Length - 1000` and tolerate some trash bytes after the EOF marker. Cf. The implementation notes.

Comment: @mkl: Where did you see that Adobe Reader starts 1000 bytes back? Also, why 1000 instead of 1024, considering that's the normal buffer size.

Comment: You are right, it's not exactly 1000. But I talked about *emulating the laxity of e.g. Adobe Reader* and by that didn't mean operating exactly like that one product but allowing a certain fairly common degree of laxity.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like:

```
List<string> allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePathHere);
return allLines[allLines.Count - 2];
```

Comment: Per the specifications, it isn't recommended to read the file line by line forward. It is recommended (as the question states) to read the file from end to start.

Comment: PDFs can be pretty big. Reading all lines like this merely to retrieve one number is a huge waste of resources.